# How to iterate through an array of objects given the keys of a starting point in Javascript/Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

If I have an array of objects which look like this:

```
const array: Array<{year: number, month: number, date: number}> = [
 {year: 2020, month: 10, date: 13},
 {year: 2021: month: 3, date: 12},
 {year: 2021: month: 9, date: 6},
 {year: 2021: month 11, date 23},
]
```

And I specify my starting position by saying I want January 10th, 2021 as my starting date so I can get:

```
 {year: 2021: month: 3, date: 12},
 {year: 2021: month: 9, date: 6},
 {year: 2021: month 11, date 23},
```

How can I make a function that can pass an arbitrary starting date and the function returns all the dates following the starting date inclusive?

Comment: This actually is an equally valid problem in javascript

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to use the [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to only get the items you need.

Inside of the comparison function I would transform the item to
a [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). From there you can compare the milliseconds to understand what items are after the date you want

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Fabio's answer, this is how you would do it:

```js
function filterDate(dates: any, fromDate: Date) {
    return dates.filter(e => e.year >= fromDate.getYear() && e.month >= fromDate.getMonth() && e.date >= fromDate.getDate())
}

filterDate(array, new Date(2021, 0, 10)) // returns three arrays
```

This is assuming your month starts from 0 as this is how JavaScript Date class starts their month.

Comment: That wouldn't work because if I'm starting from December 2020 and I have data from January 2021, `e.year >= fromDate.getYear()` is true, however `e.month >= fromDate.getMonth()` will not be for Jan 2021